# how to show rows in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

Using style attribute I want to show the cell borders of a table;

```
<table class="table-bordered table-striped table">
            <colgroup>
                <col id="Col1" />
                <col id="Col2" />
                <col id="Col3" />
                <col id="Col4" />
                <col id="Col5" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr style="border:10px">
                    <th scope="col">@T("Code")</th>
                    <th scope="col">@T("Product")</th>
                    <th scope="col">@T("Unit Price")</th>
                    <th scope="col">@T("Quantity")</th>
                    <th scope="col">@T("Value")</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

ATM looks like:
[image]
Tried something like:

```
<tr style="border:10px; border-style:solid; border-color:Black;">
```

but no joy

Answer (score 1):

If you want the border on the cell, then add it to the cell not the row.

**CSS:**

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

or inline:

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display border of each cell then you need to just add an style attribute with following value :

```
<td style="border:1px solid Black;"></td>
```

syntax of the border property is :

**border: width|style|color;**

where value of style are :

none: Defines no border
dotted: Defines a dotted border
dashed: Defines a dashed border
solid: Defines a solid border
double: Defines two borders. The width of the two borders are the same as the border-width value
groove: Defines a 3D grooved border. The effect depends on the border-color value
ridge: Defines a 3D ridged border. The effect depends on the border-color value
inset: Defines a 3D inset border. The effect depends on the border-color value
outset: Defines a 3D outset border. The effect depends on the border-color value

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you probably want to style the td, not the tr. However, your styling of the tr should show something, so my guess is that your styles are being overridden from another css file, or something. Use Fire Bug, or Dev Tools in Chrome (Right click > inspect element) and you can see the styles on your td's. You can then see which are being overridden (1), which are being applied (2), and where they are coming from (3).

[image]